# c++ decimal implementation based on integers

Tags: c++

In my trading application I have to use decimal to represent prices. I need lowest possible **latency** so the only acceptable solution would be to use int64 to represent decimal. I can configure globally that I do not need for example more then 5 digits after dot, then everywhere

```
    0.0000001 is not supported
    0.000001 is not supported
    1 should be used instead of 0.00001
    10 should be used instead of 0.0001
    100 should be used instead of 0.001
    1000 should be used instead of 0.01
    10000 should be used instead of 0.1
    100000 should be used instead of 1
    and so on
```

Are there any libraries that help to do such kind of work? I don't understand completely if I need any library, probably I should just work with `int64` and that's it? Any hints and suggestions are welcome.

**upd** I now realized that `devide` and `multiply` are not obvios at all. So i'm looking for some header only library that add some macros of function to devide/multiply fixed point stored in INT64.

Comment: Is there a reason `decimal` isn't an option?  Could you make a custom class that uses `int64` internally, such as `PrecisionDec( int int_part, int decimal_part)` that limits `decimal_part` to 0<=d<1E+06?

Comment: @CodeswithHammer I should avoid different `exponent` because math then become more complicated.

Comment: Have a look at the `FixedPrecision` class here:  https://github.com/chadkler/FinancialTypes

Comment: Sorry but what you do mean by "latency"? The CPU effort to support decimal versus float etc is honestly peanuts even when dealing with millions of records when compared to say the time taken to download from a external web service, retrieve from SQL DB etc.

Comment: i'm talking about nanoseconds, currently in low latency trading nanoseconds make sense. of course we do not do anything like "web service"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're suggesting is basically [fixed point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). It's a way of achieving decimal fraction calculations using only integer operations. It can have some speed advantages (on some systems), and if it's done correctly can avoid some of the errors introduced through floating point.

There will be libraries which can help, although the maths involved is quite simple. You might find it's easy enough to read up on the subject and implement it yourself.

Comment: especcially it's interesting how "devide" should be implemented. if I have 150.03 and 100.02 which I store as 15003 and 10001 then 150.03 / 100.02 = 1.50; 15003 / 10002 = 1.50. Shold store 1.50 as long or as double? as 150 or as 1.50?

Comment: The Wikipedia link in my answer gives a good overview of the operations. For division, you can scale up the numerator again before you do the calculation; i.e. 150.03 becomes 1500300. That means the calculation is: `1500300 / 10002 = 150`